# can't update from software updater

Tags: update-manager

After the software updater pops up with some downloads as usual [image], I tried to download but after authentication a message says " Requires installation of untrusted packages This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources" and when I hit the O.K button it does not update. Again the next day  same thing happens ,the software updater pops up. I could not update. How do I fix this issue? The screen shot is below. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update (apt-get update) from terminal, see what's failing, and then use the software sources to disable whatever is failing.

Comment: I often do the "apt-get update" from the terminal but whatever is failing I am reluctant to see and disable the failing.How do I do that. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: when you update, what does it say?

Comment: I have already uploaded the screenshot above.Any way it says "Requires installation of untrusted packages This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources".

Comment: Sorry, I meant what does the terminal (ctrl+alt+t) respond with when you try sudo apt-get update?

Comment: O.K, First it asks for my P.W and then it starts updating ,I have no idea what or which packages or software it updates.

Comment: Does it say anything like packages x & y failed? or dependencies having issues, etc? Also, have you tried what the last person said? Sorry, last edit: can you try adding "-qq" (without quotes) at the end of apt-get update?

Comment: I don't know.What happens if I add "-qq" at the end of apt-get?

Comment: it updates, but only displays errors. Usually saying --help or -h after a command in the terminal will give you the options you can use with that command.

Comment: Thanks to you, many many. I shall try that.And if problem persist I 'll pest you.

Answer (score 0):

My 14.04 just got that same issue. It's unbelievable they cannot fix that!

Solution is to open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I wonder how average users and moms will handle this. I also wonder what excuse prevents the software updater from running those same commands..